# celery run tasks if the previous task is successful

Tags: python, django, celery

I need to run four tasks but they need to run one after the other only if they are successful.

I have tried to chain them like this..but they start off independently

```
res = (mul.si(5,5) | mul.si(5,6) | mul.si(5,7) | mul.si(5,8) | mul.si(5,9) )()
```

any idea?

Comment: chain does exactly that: it runs the next task if the previous task returned successfully.

Comment: try: `(mul.s(5) | mul.s(6) | mul.s(7) | mul.s(8) | mul.s(9)(5)`

Comment: think about it: the above expression would be impossible to perform in parallel as the next step depends on the return value of the previous...

Comment: Note that this performs so quickly on my machine that the clock is not precise enough to distinguish the actual order of operation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. But you need to store the result as mentioned [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results).

But this is rarely used since it turns the asynchronous call into a synchronous one

In my example,

tasks.py is like

```
from celery import Celery
import datetime

app = Celery('tasks',backend='amqp' broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


def add_chained(args_list=list()):
    for args in args_list:
        print "Performing addtion for %s at %s" % (args, datetime.datetime.now())
        result = add.delay(*args)
        while not result.ready():
            pass
```

Result is Like this:

```
>>> import tasks
>>> tasks.add_chained([(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5)])
Performing addtion for (1, 2) at 2014-01-17 18:49:57.392357
Performing addtion for (2, 3) at 2014-01-17 18:49:57.428961
Performing addtion for (3, 4) at 2014-01-17 18:49:57.432598
Performing addtion for (4, 5) at 2014-01-17 18:49:57.435891
```